# Reading/Writing CustomDocumentProperties from xlsx file without interop

Tags: c#, xlsx, npoi

is it possible to read/write [CustomDocumentProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.customdocumentproperties) from an xlsx file without using Excel interop but purely by manipulating the XML or using a library like NPOI.

Basically, I need to in an MVC application to allow a user to download an xlsx file which has some CustomDocumentProperties pre set.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at this :
[SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/)

Especially this page might be interesting to you:
[DocumentProperties](http://spreadsheetlight.com/downloads/samplecode/DocumentProperties.cs)

Comment: The source is all there so you can easily see where to modify the ooxml

Comment: Thank you Henrik this is super useful, but as far as I can see it doesn't allow defining a custom DocumentProperty

Comment: Well.
I'd try to create a custom property with some distinct text and then find it in the OOXML.
Then it should be a breeze to add a function to SpreadSheetLight that inserts it in the same area.